# Where to define security roles?

Tags: database, security, oop, symfony, roles

I have an User and a Group Entity which both hold an array of roles.

Now I would like to keep the option open to modificate the roles, add them and so on.

Should I use constants in the classes for this or should I relate an OneToOne-relation to a table which keeps all the roles?

Best Regards,
pus.dev

User <=> Role
Group <=> Role

```
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
    }

    // we need to make sure to have at least one role
    $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

Comment: Why not use FOSUserBundle for this? It provides everything you need.

Comment: Hi switched back from FOSUserBundle to an own Bundle :)


How do i create new Roles in Symfony?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a Roles table with ManyToOne relation to each user. One row of the Roles table would contain a role(string or constant int) and a user.

Alternatively you can create a Roles table and have a ManyToMany relation with the User table. Using this you could define roles dynamically, so you don't have to hardcode the possible roles.

In the OneToMany case you could retrieve the roles by writing such a function:

```
/** @OneToMany(...) */
/** $roles contains strings */
protected $roles;

public function getRoles() {
    return $this->roles;
}
```

OR

```
/** @OneToMany(...) */
/** $roles contains integers */
protected $roles;

public function getRoles() {
    $rolesArr = array(1 => 'ROLE_ADMIN', 2 => 'ROLE_USER', 3 => 'ROLE_EDITOR'); // you should refactor $rolesArr
    $retRoles = array();
    foreach($this->roles as $role) {
        $retRoles[] = $rolesArr[$role];
    }
    return $retRoles;
}
```

In the ManyToMany case you could retrieve the roles by writing such a function:

```
/** @ManyToMany(...) */
protected $roles;
// ...
public function getRoles() {
    $retRoles = array();
    // symfony2 requires a string array
    foreach($this->roles as $role) {
        $retRoles[] = $role->getName(); // or $retRoles[] = 'ROLE_' . $role->getName();
    }
    return $retRoles;
}
```

And dont forget that your User model must implement symfony's built-in User interface.

For group roles you can do this:

```
class Group
{
    /** @ManyToMany(...) */
    protected $roles;

    public function getRoles() {
        return $this->roles;
    }
}

class User
{
   /** @ORM\Column(...) */
   protected $group;

    /** @ManyToMany(...) */
    protected $roles;
    // ...

    public function getRoles() {
        $retRoles = array();
        // symfony2 requires a string array
        $roles = $this->roles->merge($this->group->getRoles());
        foreach($roles as $role) {
            $retRoles[] = $role->getName(); // or $retRoles[] = 'ROLE_' . $role->getName();
        }
        return $retRoles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed description. I would take the ManyToMany way. Could you recommand me what you would use for properties in an Role entity?
What do properties are required to be compatible to ACLs?

Also how do I guarantee a ManyToMany with User and Group?

Comment: A group contains many users, each user has many roles, each role has many users, imho groups have nothing to do with user roles.

Comment: But the group could hold special data. For example that there is an extra Admin-Group and all members have additional the ROLE_ADMIN.

Wouldn't this be a good example when Groups holding roles would be good?

Comment: Then make a OneToMany relation between groups and roles and when in the User's getRoles method merge the return array with User's groups' roles. I will update my answer in a moment.