# How to change role hierarchy storage in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

In my project I need to store role hierarchy in database and create new roles dynamically.
In Symfony2 role hierarchy is stored in `security.yml` by default.
What have I found:

There is a service `security.role_hierarchy` (`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy`);
This service receives a roles array in constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $hierarchy)
{
    $this->hierarchy = $hierarchy;

    $this->buildRoleMap();
}
```

and the `$hierarchy` property is private.

This argument comes in constructor from `\Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension::createRoleHierarchy()`
which uses roles from config, as I understood:

```
$container->setParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles', $config['role_hierarchy']);
```

It seems me that the best way is to compile an array of roles from database and set it as an argument for the service. But I haven't yet understood how to do it.

The second way I see is to define my own `RoleHierarchy` class inherited from the base one. But since in the base `RoleHierarchy` class the `$hierarchy` property is defined as private, than I would have to redefine all the functions from the base `RoleHierarchy` class. But I don't think it is a good OOP and Symfony way...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The solution was simple.
First I created a Role entity.

```
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $parent;

    ...
}
```

after that created a RoleHierarchy service, extended from the Symfony native one. I inherited the constructor, added an EntityManager there and provided an original constructor with a new roles array instead of the old one:

```
class RoleHierarchy extends Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy
{
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param array $hierarchy
     */
    public function __construct(array $hierarchy, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct($this->buildRolesTree());
    }

    /**
     * Here we build an array with roles. It looks like a two-levelled tree - just 
     * like original Symfony roles are stored in security.yml
     * @return array
     */
    private function buildRolesTree()
    {
        $hierarchy = array();
        $roles = $this->em->createQuery('select r from UserBundle:Role r')->execute();
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            /** @var $role Role */
            if ($role->getParent()) {
                if (!isset($hierarchy[$role->getParent()->getName()])) {
                    $hierarchy[$role->getParent()->getName()] = array();
                }
                $hierarchy[$role->getParent()->getName()][] = $role->getName();
            } else {
                if (!isset($hierarchy[$role->getName()])) {
                    $hierarchy[$role->getName()] = array();
                }
            }
        }
        return $hierarchy;
    }
}
```

... and redefined it as a service:

```
<services>
    <service id="security.role_hierarchy" class="Acme\UserBundle\Security\Role\RoleHierarchy" public="false">
        <argument>%security.role_hierarchy.roles%</argument>
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

That's all.
Maybe, there is something unnecessary in my code. Maybe it is possible to write better. But I think, that main idea is evident now.

Comment: @zls How can I get the path of role in your code? Like this :  `- { path: ^/cart/checkout, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }`

Comment: Nice thanks. i give the $hierarchy array to the buildRolesTree Method, to have it extended as needed, this way you can have a base set of role hierarchy still definied in your security.yml

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't work anymore since symfony 2.8 if you have not set any roles_hierarchy roles in yml since it doesn't pass this line https://github.com/symfony/security-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L187

Answer (score 14):

I had do the same thing like zIs (to store the RoleHierarchy in the database) but i cannot load the complete role hierarchy inside the Constructor like zIs did, because i had to load a custom doctrine filter inside the `kernel.request` event. The Constructor will be called **before** the `kernel.request` so it was no option for me.

Therefore I checked the security component and found out that `Symfony` calls a custom `Voter` to check the `roleHierarchy` according to the users role:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchyInterface;

/**
 * RoleHierarchyVoter uses a RoleHierarchy to determine the roles granted to
 * the user before voting.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class RoleHierarchyVoter extends RoleVoter
{
    private $roleHierarchy;

    public function __construct(RoleHierarchyInterface $roleHierarchy, $prefix = 'ROLE_')
    {
        $this->roleHierarchy = $roleHierarchy;

        parent::__construct($prefix);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function extractRoles(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles($token->getRoles());
    }
}
```

The getReachableRoles Method returns all roles the user can be. For example:

```
           ROLE_ADMIN
         /             \
     ROLE_SUPERVISIOR  ROLE_BLA
        |               |
     ROLE_BRANCH       ROLE_BLA2
       |
     ROLE_EMP

or in Yaml:
ROLE_ADMIN:       [ ROLE_SUPERVISIOR, ROLE_BLA ]
ROLE_SUPERVISIOR: [ ROLE_BRANCH ]
ROLE_BLA:         [ ROLE_BLA2 ]
```

If the user has the ROLE_SUPERVISOR role assigned the Method returns the roles ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_BRANCH and ROLE_EMP (Role-Objects or Classes, which implementing RoleInterface)

Furthermore this custom voter will be disabled if there is no RoleHierarchy defined in the `security.yaml`

```
private function createRoleHierarchy($config, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!isset($config['role_hierarchy'])) {
            $container->removeDefinition('security.access.role_hierarchy_voter');

            return;
        }

        $container->setParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles', $config['role_hierarchy']);
        $container->removeDefinition('security.access.simple_role_voter');
    }
```

To solve my issue I created my own custom Voter and extended the RoleVoter-Class, too:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\RoleVoter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Acme\Foundation\UserBundle\Entity\Group;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class RoleHierarchyVoter extends RoleVoter {

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $prefix = 'ROLE_') {

        $this->em = $em;

        parent::__construct($prefix);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function extractRoles(TokenInterface $token) {

        $group = $token->getUser()->getGroup();

        return $this->getReachableRoles($group);
    }

    public function getReachableRoles(Group $group, &$groups = array()) {

        $groups[] = $group;

        $children = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeFoundationUserBundle:Group')->createQueryBuilder('g')
                        ->where('g.parent = :group')
                        ->setParameter('group', $group->getId())
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getResult();

        foreach($children as $child) {
            $this->getReachableRoles($child, $groups);
        }

        return $groups;
    }
}
```

One Note: My Setup is similar to zls ones. My Definition for the role (in my case I called it Group):

```
Acme\Foundation\UserBundle\Entity\Group:
    type: entity
    table: sec_groups
    id: 
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 50
        role:
            type: string
            length: 20
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: Group
```

And the userdefinition:

```
Acme\Foundation\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: sec_users
    repositoryClass: Acme\Foundation\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        username:
            type: string
            length: 30
        salt:
            type: string
            length: 32
        password:
            type: string
            length: 100
        isActive:
            type: boolean
            column: is_active
    manyToOne:
        group:
            targetEntity: Group
            joinColumn:
                name: group_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
```

Maybe this helps someone.

Comment: Again; I'm removing your apology for bad English because you have excellent English!

Comment: thanks for this.one question: how did you replace symfony's voter with your's?

Answer (score 3):

I developped a bundle.

You can find it at https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/RoleHierarchyBundle

Answer (score 2):

My solution was inspired by the solution provided by zls. His solution worked perfectly for me, but the one-to-many relation between the roles meant having one huge role tree, which would become hard to maintain. Also, a problem might occur if two different roles wanted to inherit one same role (as there could only be one parent). That's why I decided to create a many-to-many solution. Instead of having only the parent in the role class, I have first put this in the role class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_permission",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $children;
```

After that I rewrote the buildRolesTree function like so:

```
private function buildRolesTree()
{
    $hierarchy = array();
    $roles = $this->em->createQuery('select r, p from AltGrBaseBundle:Role r JOIN r.children p')->execute();

    foreach ($roles as $role)
    {
        /* @var $role Role */
        if (count($role->getChildren()) > 0)
        {
            $roleChildren = array();

            foreach ($role->getChildren() as $child)
            {
                /* @var $child Role */
                $roleChildren[] = $child->getRole();
            }

            $hierarchy[$role->getRole()] = $roleChildren;
        }
    }

    return $hierarchy;
}
```

The result is the ability to create several easily maintained trees. For instance, you can have a tree of roles defining the ROLE_SUPERADMIN role and entirely separate tree defining a ROLE_ADMIN role with several roles shared between them. Although circular connections should be avoided (roles should be laid out as trees, without any circular connections between them), there should be no problems if it actually happens. I haven't tested this, but going through the buildRoleMap code, it is obvious it dumps any duplicates. This should also mean it won't get stuck in endless loops if the circular connection occurs, but this definitely needs more testing.

I hope this proves helpful to someone.

Comment: thanks @andre-mohar your answer was really help full to my, but i think using nested sets will be the best solution for node trees like these, why didn´t you implement it  in this solution ?

Comment: @metalvarez: Hm, I've taken a brief look into [Doctrine's nested sets](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/hierarchical-data.html#nested-set) which seems to be what you're talking about. I agree, seems very promising. Sadly, I have many other project-related prioritized things that require my attention. But I will definitely be looking to refactor my existing code and I'll update my answer then, if anyone else does not post the updated solution. Thank you for bringing this up.

Answer (score 0):

Since role hierarchy don't change often, this a quick class to cache to memcached.

```
<?php

namespace .....;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchyInterface;
use Lsw\MemcacheBundle\Cache\MemcacheInterface;

/**
 * RoleHierarchy defines a role hierarchy.
 */
class RoleHierarchy implements RoleHierarchyInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @var MemcacheInterface 
     */
    private $memcache;

    /**
     *
     * @var array 
     */
    private $hierarchy;

    /**
     *
     * @var array 
     */
    protected $map;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param array $hierarchy An array defining the hierarchy
     */
    public function __construct(array $hierarchy, MemcacheInterface $memcache)
    {
        $this->hierarchy = $hierarchy;

        $roleMap = $memcache->get('roleMap');

        if ($roleMap) {
            $this->map = unserialize($roleMap);
        } else {
            $this->buildRoleMap();
            // cache to memcache
            $memcache->set('roleMap', serialize($this->map));
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getReachableRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $reachableRoles = $roles;
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            if (!isset($this->map[$role->getRole()])) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($this->map[$role->getRole()] as $r) {
                $reachableRoles[] = new Role($r);
            }
        }

        return $reachableRoles;
    }

    protected function buildRoleMap()
    {
        $this->map = array();
        foreach ($this->hierarchy as $main => $roles) {
            $this->map[$main] = $roles;
            $visited = array();
            $additionalRoles = $roles;
            while ($role = array_shift($additionalRoles)) {
                if (!isset($this->hierarchy[$role])) {
                    continue;
                }

                $visited[] = $role;
                $this->map[$main] = array_unique(array_merge($this->map[$main], $this->hierarchy[$role]));
                $additionalRoles = array_merge($additionalRoles, array_diff($this->hierarchy[$role], $visited));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I hope this will help you.

```
function getRoles()
{

  //  return array(1=>'ROLE_ADMIN',2=>'ROLE_USER'); 
   return array(new UserRole($this));
}
```

You can get a good idea from,
 [Where to define security roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024545/symfony2-where-define-roles)

http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/        ( 2012 July 28 )

Comment: This has nothing to do with the role hierarchy, only with a user's roles.