# How to change role hierarchy storage in Symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to change hieharchy storage like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602337/how-to-change-role-hierarchy-storage-in-symfony2). I overrided `security.role_hierarchy` service.
service:

```
services:
    security.role_hierarchy:
        class: AppBundle\Role\DynamicRoleHierarchy
        public: false
        arguments: [%security.role_hierarchy.roles%, "@=service('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager').getRepository('AppBundle:Role')"]
```

DynamicRoleHierarchy:

```
class DynamicRoleHierarchy extends RoleHierarchy
{
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param array $hierarchy An array defining the hierarchy
     */
    public function __construct(array $hierarchy, RoleRepository $roleRepository)
    {
        // Actually, here I get $hierarchy from DB
        $hierarchy = [
            'ROLE_ADMIN' => [
                'ROLE_USER'
            ]
        ];

        parent::__construct($hierarchy);
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but only if there is something in `role_hierarchy` section in security.yml. If there is any text then hierarchy will work. For example:

```
// file security.yml
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        aaa:       bbb
```

But if there is no `role_hierarchy` section or it is empty then hierarchy doesn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: You can simply remove the security.role_hierarchy.roles parameter from the service definition and just inject the entity manager.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198846/symfony3-how-to-store-user-roles-in-database) might help you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the config contains no `role_hierarchy` configuration, the [role hierarchy voter is removed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L175-L179). Instead of trying to replace the built-in role hierarchy service, I would rather register a custom role hierarchy voter (and make sure to remove the built-in one if it conflicts with your implementation).