# Role Management Symfony and NodeJs

Tags: php, node.js, symfony

I'm currently working on a *Symfony* project (that we'll call `example.com`) on which I need to change the Role management. I've already modified the php code according to the new hierarchy of role.

However, we also have a NodeJS server that is responsible for a service of video streaming. When a client connects to the webservice he access on a webpage ( `example.com/webcam` generated thanks to symfony/twig) that contain JS opening a connection to a Socket. This socket is directly connected to the nodeJS server running on a custom port (`wss://example.com:9900`).

The image below summarizes this.

[image: Schema of functionnement]

As I said earlier, I need to include a role management. However, at the moment, everything about the role is located in the symfony code. I don't really want to export it to the nodeJS server because it would be harder to maintain it later (two places where modification is needed) and because as far as I know there is no Role management that is exactly the same in  nodeJS.

So i've thought of making the websocket traffic pass by symfony and then sending it back to the client as in the schema below 
[image: Schema of probable futur functionnement]

However:

- I don't know if it's the best way to do it so if you're aware of another method or if you think it would be better to duplicate the role management logic on both webserver, I would be  thankful of your advices
- If that's a great method how can I create an efficient websocket on symfony redirecting the traffic ?

Comment: No idea how to help you with the problem but I do like your images.

Comment: Do you have a separate server for storing the database? In this case it may be an idea to store all available roles also in the database and check whether the user has access to the right roles directly in the database through Node.js

Comment: Yes, roles are stored in another database so I can access them with both Symfony and nodeJS. However role hierarchy is stored in a yml symfony file. So if I want to know every right a user has, I need to access both the database and the config file. But yes, that's another possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there isn't really an out-of-the-box solution for this problem. In order to share the roles between Symfony and the Node.js server it is necessary to define them at a single place (e.g. in the database) and from there inject them in both servers. In Symfony you can persist the role hierarchy into a database: [see example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11916488/3605831)

In this way you have a single point where the roles are stored which means the Node.js server can read all roles from the database.

Note: someone in the comments of the example mentioned that this example will not work for Symfony 2.8 (you didn't specified your Symfony version). If you use Symfony 2.8, you could use [this](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/RoleHierarchyBundle) unmaintained bundle as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Only what can I suggest to use JWT auhtentication and everytime call symfony and check if token is correct, or you can store the secret key(pem file) in nodejs server and in symfony issue token  and check if token is valid in nodejs server, and in token you can put roles.

Another solution ia to use OAuth2 and authenticate it there.